# Why does my monitor go black after 15 minutes?

Tags: display

My monitor goes black after about 15 minutes. It is not the video card as I have already tested that. After leaving the monitor off for a while and then turning it back on, the image comes back, but then the pattern begins again.

I would like to know which parts need to be replaced.

Comment: All caps? Really?

Comment: Oh, and a lot of computers turn the monitor off after 15 minutes of idle time by design.  Make sure this isn't what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

These days, just replace the monitor.  See if you can borrow one off a friend to check it is the monitor first.

Comment: I know for sure its the monitor, I have already checked power setting, screen saver, video etc.  I want to dabble with the monitor repair and just wondering what failed part would cause this. the lamp?, the inverter?

Comment: "Dabbling" with monitor repair (especially CRT monitors) is a dangerous business.  If you don't know exactly what you're doing you could end up zapping yourself with 10,000 volts (and that's not nice).  You'd need to obtain detailed schematics from the manufacturer to even have a slim chance of solving the problem.

Comment: A similar warning convinced me to leave the dabbling outside the monitor. It's a lot like dabbling with old explosives or firearms.